# Renamea file with new suffix

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

how can i rename a file eith new suffix known only the prefix ?

Example:

I have a file called: 
a_proof.txt

How can i rename in:
a_proof.tmp

I have to use the linux shell like CSH and KSH, and the most used programs on linux Red Hat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using BASH features you can use `basename`:

```
mv a_proof.txt `basename 'a_proof.txt' '.txt'`.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename:

```
mv a_proof.txt a_proof.tmp
```

Rename with backup, also called copy:

```
cp a_proof.txt a_proof.tmp
```